# How do I tell Pyinstaller to use an .EXE thats in the Scripts folder?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

for example if I

`pip install ffmpeg-python`

and run

`os.system('ffmpeg -version')`

it will print ffmpeg's version.

but if I save this line to main.py and `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` and run it, Windows can't find ffmpeg.

How do I tell pyinstaller to use the ffmpeg.exe thats in the Scripts folder?

**Edit:** I figured it out, answered below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is how i did it:

```
#test.py
import sys
import os

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    basedir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
    basedir = str(basedir)

os.system(basedir+'/ffmpeg.exe -version') 
#works without the .exe also
```

and for pyinstaller you write

```
pyinstaller test.py --add-data "ffmpeg.exe;." --onefile
```

ffmpeg.exe is in the same folder as the test.py

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by defining full path of local directory. After that I added this path to my EXE files in the current directory and run them. So try this:

```
from os import path
this_script_dir = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))
ffmpeg_path = this_script_dir + '\\ffmpeg.exe'
```